# How to set up gitignore so file shows up as existing but doesnt change?

Tags: git, github, environment-variables, atom-editor, gitignore

I'm making a project using git and github and I have a .env file that I want to show as existing but not actually change contents.
So for example i have it set to default as

```
KEY=""
SECRET=""
```

This content is on my remote repo and I have added the file to the .gitignore *after* I made the initial commit so that hopefully it won't stage any keys I added but will keep the initial content. The file changes do show up in my unstaged changes when I made an edit however. This also happens with a databse file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+file+ignore+changes

Comment: The Git FAQ [explains why this won't work in some detail](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile).